# Unable to access WordPress after auto installing using Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS aptitude

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I've installed the following items seqentially:

apt-get install apache2

apt-get install mysql-server-5.1

```
root@wp-companyweb01:/home/administrator# apt-get install wordpress
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjs-cropper libjs-prototype libjs-scriptaculous libphp-phpmailer
  libphp-snoopy php-gettext tinymce wordpress-l10n
Suggested packages:
  mail-transport-agent curl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjs-cropper libjs-prototype libjs-scriptaculous libphp-phpmailer
  libphp-snoopy php-gettext tinymce wordpress wordpress-l10n
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,890kB of archives.
After this operation, 29.5MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe libjs-prototype 1.6.1-1 [34.9kB]
Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe libjs-scriptaculous 1.8.3-1 [127kB]
Get:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe libjs-cropper 1.2.1-1 [136kB]
Get:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe libphp-phpmailer 5.1-1 [77.0kB]
Get:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe libphp-snoopy 1.2.4-1 [15.3kB]
Get:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe php-gettext 1.0.9-1 [15.9kB]
Get:7 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe tinymce 3.2.7-1 [442kB]
Get:8 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe wordpress 2.9.2-1ubuntu1 [2,017kB]
Get:9 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe wordpress-l10n 2.9.2-1ubuntu1 [5,025kB]
Fetched 7,890kB in 38s (203kB/s)
Selecting previously deselected package libjs-prototype.
(Reading database ... 48847 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libjs-prototype (from .../libjs-prototype_1.6.1-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libjs-scriptaculous.
Unpacking libjs-scriptaculous (from .../libjs-scriptaculous_1.8.3-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libjs-cropper.
Unpacking libjs-cropper (from .../libjs-cropper_1.2.1-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libphp-phpmailer.
Unpacking libphp-phpmailer (from .../libphp-phpmailer_5.1-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libphp-snoopy.
Unpacking libphp-snoopy (from .../libphp-snoopy_1.2.4-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package php-gettext.
Unpacking php-gettext (from .../php-gettext_1.0.9-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package tinymce.
Unpacking tinymce (from .../tinymce_3.2.7-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package wordpress.
Unpacking wordpress (from .../wordpress_2.9.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package wordpress-l10n.
Unpacking wordpress-l10n (from .../wordpress-l10n_2.9.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Setting up libjs-prototype (1.6.1-1) ...
Setting up libjs-scriptaculous (1.8.3-1) ...
Setting up libjs-cropper (1.2.1-1) ...
Setting up libphp-phpmailer (5.1-1) ...
Setting up libphp-snoopy (1.2.4-1) ...
Setting up php-gettext (1.0.9-1) ...
Setting up tinymce (3.2.7-1) ...

Setting up wordpress (2.9.2-1ubuntu1) ...

Setting up wordpress-l10n (2.9.2-1ubuntu1) ...
```

However when I tried to access it with the following URL, it failed:

http://wp-companyweb01/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php

Nothing comes up.

Comment: Is there any difference between the apt-get install and the manually download version of the same wordpress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I just found out that the connect user is granted to "localhost" instead of the servername.

so the solution is by go to mysql and grant:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE wp_itreewebdb;
mysql> CREATE USER wordpressuser;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR wordpressuser = PASSWORD("wordpresspassword");
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_itreewebdb.* TO 'wordpressuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'wordpresspassword';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

now it all works.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check. Is your .htaccess file been overwritten with the upgrade? If so, you'll want to look at some documentation to read how it should be set up. If you can't find any let me know & I could post back some resources.

Also, log into mysql and find out what rows 1 (or two) and 39 (or 40) have to say in regards to the site url.

Also, does http://wp-companyweb01/wordpress come up at all? How about any other site?

Any additional information you could post would be helpful.

Comment: thanks Tim, It seems that i'm now stuck in database connection issue, "Error establishing a database connection".